# Not Able to Start PDI GUI from Spoon.bat in PDI Community Edition

Tags: java, windows, pentaho, kettle, pdi

System Details:

```
Windows 7 Professional
Processor :Intel Core i3
RAM: 3GB
System Type : 32 Bit Operating System.
```

PDI Version:

```
pdi-ce-6.0.0.0-353
```

Steps Performed:

```
 1. Extracted the Zip File pdi-ce-6.0.0.0-353.zip into G:\ Drive
 2. Created Environment Variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME and set value to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
```

Error Received While Executing Spoon.bat from cmd:

```
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe

G:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-6.0.0.0-353\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx256m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-6.0.0.0-353.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32  
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe

G:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-6.0.0.0-353\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx256m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-6.0.0.0-353.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32  
DEBUG: Using PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe

G:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-6.0.0.0-353\data-integration>start "Spoon" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx256m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-6.0.0.0-353.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32
```

Comment: Where is the error you encountered? Can you provide it?

Comment: @A. Di Matteo the clicking on spoon.bat does nothing, so error or trace while executing same from cmd give the trace posted in error section in my post. Though its doesn't seems error but thats what I've with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default XMX parameter Value in spoon.bat was 2048M. which was not starting Jre, so earlier i changed it into 256M. All of sudden i then tried **Changing** XMX parameter Value in spoon.bat file  from **XMX256m to Xmx1024m**, and wola it **Worked**. Don't know the reason or logic for this XMX stands for and what value should be here mathematically supporting your System configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the `xmx` parameter from `2048M` to `1024M` and **Pentaho** started working.

```
PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Make sure to  update environmental varibles required for Pentaho start up.

```
PENTAHO_HOME
PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click and open spoon.bat file change the xmx value in below string to a lower value as per your system configuration 
PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx1024m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

restart pdi and this should work.